# Access query to eliminate duplicates of a key found in 2 columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have a Access database where I have a set of data.

```
Sales Order No.   & Line number
123456                 000010
123456                 000020
123458                 000010
123459                 000010
123459                 000010
123459                 000020
```

The two columns need to be linked together and considered as one key.
I need to eliminate the duplicates where a duplicates exists as the entire key
in my example this is order 123459 000010  is the only one duplicated here.

how can I write this query to delete this duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Here ya go :)  This is of course an example - alter to suite your needs. It of course doesnt do anything other than find the duplicates. It is easy however to change this query to a delete statement.

You could even do this as well, but the previous covers it quite well

```
SELECT
    name, email, name+email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to remove the dupe from a list, just use *group by*:

```
Select 
    [Sales Order No.],
    [Line number]
From
    YourTable
Group By
    [Sales Order No.],
    [Line number]
```

will return:

```
123456                 000010
123456                 000020
123458                 000010
123459                 000010
123459                 000020
```